# Granularity of Activity scope when tracing using system.diagnostics server side

Tags: c#, .net, trace, system.diagnostics

I'm using the tracing functionality in System.Diagnostics, and have hit a problem of sorts. I've implemented tracing itself in my application with no issues, but am struggling with what some best practices would be. Or to put it more simply, I understand how, but not why.

I have a RESTful client/server app, where the client is a web browser, and the server doesn't make any calls anywhere else (No WCF calls to other server processes for example).

The concept I'm trying to get right is the concept of an Activity. Traces are conceptually grouped together, allowing you to see all traces messages for a particular Activity. During a single page load, I'll make a number of calls to various classes, to get data from the database, to perform business logic on the data, etc.

How granular should an Activity be? The extremes of either 'a page load is a single Activity' or 'each method call is a new sub Activity'? Or is something in the middle, perhaps: 'the data access call, and the business logic call on page load are both sub Activities, and everything else comes under the main page load Activity'?

The other concept is that of the `CorrelationManager.StartLogicalOperation` method. Again, the implementation of this isn't tricky, but understanding why to use it is. This seems to allow you to group a set of traces together under a logicalOperation name. There seems to be an overlap here with the concept of a trace Activity group however. Should these two concepts be used together? Why/In what situations would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

I think those concepts (Activity and LogicalOperation) are orthogonal.  You could have an Activity that has many LogicalOperations inside.  Or, you could have a LogicalOperation where the Activity could change.  I would guess it would be more common that the Activity is at a higher level than the LogicalOperation.

It is probably not very helpful of me to say so, but it is up to you do decide what makes most sense to you and your application as far as organizing your logging.

I suspect that it would be common to have a single request result in a single Activity.

You might find it helpful to have helper classes to make it easier to manage the Activity and LogicalOperation.  Something like this:

```
class ActivityScope : IDisposable
{
  Guid oldActivity;
  ActivityScope()
  {
    oldActivity = System.Diagnostics.CorrelationManager.ActivityId;
    System.Diagnostics.CorrelationManager.ActivityId = Guid.NewGuid();
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    System.Diagnostics.CorrelationManager.ActivityId = oldActivity;
  }
}

class LogicalOperationScope : IDisposable
{
  public LogicalOperationScope(string logicalOperation)
  {
    System.Diagnostics.CorrelationManager.StartLogicalOperation(logicalOperation);
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    System.Diagnostics.CorrelationManager.StopLogicalOperation();
  }
}
```

You can use them like this:

```
void ServiceARequest()
{
  using (new ActivityScope())
  {
    //Do some stuff

    using (new LogicalOperationScope("SomeWork"))
    {
      DoSomeWork();

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
        using (new LogicalOperationScope(string.Format("nested {0}", i))
        {
          DoNestedWork(i);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

void DoSomeWork()
{
  using (new LogicalOperationScope("DoSomeWork"))
  {
  }
}

void DoNestedWork(int level)
{
}
```

Obviously my example is heavy on diagnostic code and light on real code, but you get the idea.  If it makes sense to you to have an ActivityId or a LogicalOperation, try managing them with "scope" classes similar to this.

Good luck!